# Check if input is of correct type

Tags: c++, validation, templates, input

I have a template class which can take all kinds of types: int, double etc. I want to check if the user has inputted the correct type. If the object was instantiated with int the user should input an int, if it was with double he should input a double and so on. I want to be able to do this no matter if the input comes from file or keyboard. I have 2 questions.

1. Should I do the checking in the definition of the ">>" operator overloading?
2. How do I do the checking? Do I create a template function that checks for any kind of type?

I want something like this:

```
template <class Ttype>
class foo 
{
    Ttype a,b,c; 
    friend istream &operator>> <>( istream &input, foo<Ttype> &X );
    //methods
};

template <class Ttype> istream &operator>>( istream &input, foo<Ttype> &X )
{
    //check if X.a,X.b,X.c are of Ttype
    input>>X.a>>X.b>>X.c;
}

int main()
{
    foo<int> a;
    cin>>a;

    foo<double> b;
    cin>>b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `X.a` has to be `Ttype` because you declared it to be.  If you really wanted to check you could `static_assert(std::is_same<Ttype, decltype(X.a)>::value, "not the same");` but that will never fire.

Comment: you could use boost::spirit, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/abstracts/attributes/primitive_attributes.html) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't check the input before you have read it. The only thing I can think of is to read the input into a string (which will always work for text files or stdin) and try to convert it into your expected type. While converting you can look for exceptions.

Comment: And how do i check if the types match?  Do i  use typeinfo on Ttype?

Comment: Just use a conversion method and check if exceptions occur. You can specialize your template functions for several types and call the right conversion method in each (like `atoi`/`atof` or some STL equivalent if there is on).

Comment: neither of those functions throw exceptions.

Comment: True. For C++11 you might use `std::stoi` and so on. Otherwise if boost is an option `boost::lexical_cast` may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems all you want is to try to read from the `istream` and fail if the reading fails.  In that case you can use the implicit bool-likeness of the `istream` after the extraction operation.

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
    T a,b,c;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Foo& X ) {
      if (!(input >> X.a >> X.b >> X.c)) { // examine the istream
        std::cerr << "extraction failed\n";
      }
      return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution. But two additional thoughts.

I'm not exactly sure but wouldn't this cause trouble for the last read operation (EOF)? Cause EOF will set the failbit as well but it is no real error. I might be wrong here. Maybe an additional check is helpful to determine if it was EOF. Something like checking explicitly `fail()` and if this is true also check if it wasn't `eof()`.

Second thought. Will this fail for e.g. `int` if the input is something like `5.0`?

Comment: `eof` is not set until you try to read *beyond* the end of the stream.  If you entered something like `1 2.0 3` it would fail as expected, if you did `1 2 3.5` it would succeed but leave the `.5` in the stream.  If you want to work around that then you'll have to consume the input as strings.. how exactly to move from there is not the clearest.  You could make a string stream for each string and check to see if the whole stream is consumed.